# Ajax call - Append the structure of the php echo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am confused a little bit and I have no clues what am I looking for.
Although I will post here important parts so you may figureout and help me.

> **A part of PHP file:**

```
if (empty($vid) || empty($entry)) {
    $broken = TRUE;
}

if(!$broken) {
    $video = parseVideoEntry($entry);

    echo "
        <div class=\"video_wrap\">
            <div class=\"video_thumbnail\">
                <a href=\"{$video->watchURL}\">
                    <img src=\"$video->thumbnailURL\">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- More of structure parts here -->
    ";
}
```

> **A part of HTML structure:**

```
<form action="" method="GET" style="margin: 5% 0;" id="youtube_fetch">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID_HERE" id="videoID_input" />
    <input type="submit" id="fetch_submit" />
</form>
```

> **A part of jQuery / Ajax call:**

```
$('#fetch_submit').on('click', function (e) {
    var videoID = $('#videoID_input').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/YouTube_API_Fetch_ID.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: videoID },
        success: function (state) {
            var newState = $.trim(state);

            if (newState == '')
                alert('Return an Error later!');
            else
                console.log(state);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Ok so when I put valid youtube ID into the input field, it will return the else from ajax call (echo the html structure in console log).

The part that I don't know how to deal with is: "How to get that echoed HTML content/structure and append it into the `<div id="youtube_content"></div>` for example or directly to the `body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.html()` method:

```
$('#youtube_content').html(state);
```

---

**References:**

- [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
$('#fetch_submit').on('click', function (e) {
    var videoID = $('#videoID_input').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/YouTube_API_Fetch_ID.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: videoID },
        success: function (state) {
            var newState = $.trim(state);

            if (newState == '')
                alert('Return an Error later!');
            else {
                $('<div />', {
                    id: 'youtube_content'
                }).appendTo('body');

                $('#youtube_content').html(state);
            }
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```